# fastnlmeanfilter linking error

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



 int main()
{
   // load the image

Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\prashant naresh\\Documents\\Visual Studio      2010\\Projects\\nonlocalfilter\\image.jpg");


if(!img.data) {
    cout << "File not found" << endl;
    return -1;
}



// show it in a window
namedWindow( "Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow("Image", img);

// image window will immediately disappear if the program ends, so
// we'll wait for a keypress, indefinitely
waitKey();

// do a simple transformation: convert to grayscale

// first copy the image
Mat img_gray = img.clone();
Mat img1;
cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
fastNlMeansDenoising(img_gray,img1,3.0,7,21);
imshow("Image", img1);
waitKey();
return 0;
 }
```

ERROR:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,float,int,int)" (?fastNlMeansDenoising@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@MHH@Z) referenced in function _main

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\users\prashant naresh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\nonlocalfilter\Debug\nonlocalfilter.exe  nonlocalfilter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you forgot to link against opencv_photo249.lib  // or whatever version you're using

Answer (score 0):

You have some linking problem.

Try again to configure Opencv 2.4.8 or 2.49 with Visual studio by [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-VgWxkVp2w) Procedure.

Hope this will helps you.
Cheers

Comment: Hi Abc, welcome to SO and thank you for your answer. Since links can become broken over time, this video may not be around to help future visitors. It is much better to write out the procedure in your own words as an answer. Do you think you could edit your answer to do that? Thanks very much!